Modifying a Bundled .NET 7 Application
I am attempting to reverse a .NET 7 program and patch it, but it is a bundled file.
When importing the EXE into dnSpy I get the headings of a PE file (.text, etc.) and nothing else. However, if I start debugging the EXE I can see all of the DLLs that are loaded, including the main module the application is using (program is "cracktest.exe" and the main module is "cracktest.dll".
When modifying the module using dnSpy, I can save the DLL to my file system but I cannot get the application to use this new DLL.
My question is how can I modify the "cracktest.dll" module and save it so that the program will use it?
I have noticed this PR on dnSpy: https://github.com/dnSpyEx/dnSpy/pull/49 regarding bundled EXEs but it seems to be incomplete, are there other methods to achieving this, thanks.
